# Change background on different anchor link using jquery

Tags: jquery, scroll, background-image, anchor

I need to change a div background depending on link anchor. I use an onepage style website that changes page anchor link on scroll, so i need to change a div "bg" background when i scroll to different anchor link. For example:

If link is http://example.com/#about
then

```
<div class="bg" style="background-image:url(http://example.com/about.png)
```

If link is http://example.com/#portfolio
then

```
<div class="bg" style="background-image:url(http://example.com/portfolio.png)
```

If link is http://example.com/#skills
then

```
<div class="bg" style="background-image:url(http://example.com/skills.png)
```

I know that i can make it using css but i need to use jquery. I need to change background depending on link anchor and not by clicking an element, because when i scroll to the page anchor link is changing.

Comment: So you change the active anchor either by clicking on it, either by scrolling to the portion of content that is linked with that anchor, right ? You need to share your html structure together with the jquery that makes that possbile. Also, show what have you tried to achieve what you want

Comment: You can change the background image based on the url hash via css?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NOTE I have changed to `hashchange load` to trigger both events

http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/85regbvt/

```js
$(window).on('hashchange load', function(e) {
  let hash = location.hash? location.hash.substring(1) : “home”;
  let URL = "http://example.com/" + hash + ".png";
  $(".bg").css({
    "background-image": "url("+URL+")"
  })
});
```

for variable image names not matching the hash:

```js
const images = { "home":"images/default.png","about":"images/about.png","portfolio":"images/folio.gif"...};
$(window).on('hashchange load', function(e) {
  let hash = location.hash? location.hash.substring(1) : "home";
  $(".bg").css({
    "background-image": "url("+images[hash]+")"
  })
});
```

Comment: This is very good solution but my image urls are not permanently, i need to change them. So i need variables like var = $image1, var = $image2 e.t.c So for example on hash #about  get $image1, on hash #skill get $image2 e.t.c

Comment: Excellent! Is working perfect, the only problem is on first page load script is not running. I have to scroll to execute script.

Comment: “home” gives error so i changed to "home". Is working like before but script still don't run on page load. When i call for example http://example.com/#about i dont get any image, only after scrolling.

Comment: First load gives always empty image ,with or without hash. Script is running only on scroll.

Comment: Yes is working. That was my fault. I had 'hashchange' instead of 'hashchange load'. Thank you!